JsonLogging not working with Spring boot 3.2.2 and Graalvm java 21
Added these two dependencies in pom.xml and created logback.xml inside resources folder:
<!-- DEPENDENCIES TO ENABLE JSON LOGGING -->
<dependency>
<groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
<version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
<artifactId>janino</artifactId>
<version>${janino.version}</version>
</dependency>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="jsonLogging" source="jsonLogging"/>
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <if condition='property("jsonLogging").equals("true")'>
            <then>
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>{ "timestamp": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z',UTC}", "level": "%level", "version": "1", "service": "my-service", "thread": "%thread", "logger": "%logger", "method": "%method", "message": "%message" }%n
                    </pattern>
                </encoder>
            </then>
            <else>
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS,UTC} %5p [%thread:%X{X-B3-TraceId}:%X{X-B3-SpanId}] %logger{40} - %msg%n
                    </pattern>
                </encoder>
            </else>
        </if>

    </appender>
    <logger name="jsonLogger" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>
</configuration>


Also added jsonLogging=true in application.properties.
This is working with other service, but not in mine.
Sl4j version: 2.0.6
Expecting logs in json format but not coming.
Tried googling but cant get any solutions
